# When using Python Tensorflow input shape (53,))... what's going on with this comma?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I'm confused by the following line of code:

```py
input_img = Input(shape=(53,))
```

I have a batch of 52 images but how can a tuple have nothing after the comma? What does this mean?

Comment: In case of images,should'n it be something like this `shape=(28,28,3)` and the expected input to the layer are 4 dimensions as `(None,28,28,3)` and the first one is batch size

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat you could be right here. looking into this now. I was following an example from here: https://www.edureka.co/blog/autoencoders-tutorial/

Comment: normally, just use `input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function **Input** excepts a tuple for the argument **shape**

Using the comma allows you to define a tuple with a single item. If you simply used (53) or 53, it would be interpreted as an integer:

```
type( 53 )
<class 'int'>
type( (53) )
<class 'int'>
type( (53,) )
<class 'tuple'>
```

This is because the simple brackets are used in computations hence cannot be parsed a tuples:

```
(53) + 2 # would raise an error if (53) was a tuple
(53 + 1)*2 # would also raise an error if (53+1) was a tuple
```

So in order to define a tuple with a single item, you have to add the comma: (53,)

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as a scalar, but is interpreted as a shape.

If you are confused, you can look at how list can abuse this too, for example:

```
print([
       0,
       1,
       2,  # <- This comma is unnecessary but won't break your code
])
```

> [0, 1, 2]

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I don't see what you mean you're simply printing a list there?

Comment: Look at the last comma ;)

Comment: I see this combined with A Co's answer makes sense!